# An exception when getting the param passed by model

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4

Basically one of my model passes a data list into the view, like this

```
public ActionResult ModealA(){
   list a ;
   ...
   ...
   return View(a)
}
```

In the view, I wrote like this:

```
@foreach(var temp in Model.a){
  ...
}
```

Then I got a exception saying that

```
System.Collections.Generic.List<UniBlue.Models.KYC>' does not contain a definition for 'a'
```

Can anybody tell me what part I wrote wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Model is the list itself in your case

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you say `return View(a)`, then `a` itself is the model.  It should be like this:

```
@foreach(UniBlue.Models.KYC temp in Model)   // Model refers to the list "a"
{
    // ...
}
```

Comment: Mn.... excellent answer! what if I need to pass two data lists?
Also.... what's the point of setting strong type when creating a view? @McGarnagle

Comment: @user1804033 if you need to pass two lists, then wrap both into a new class.  The only point of setting a strong type in a view, as far as I know, is so that intellisense can help in Visual Studio.

Comment: mn..... will that wrap class a inner class? or I should make a new class any where in the project?

Comment: @user1804033 just make a new class -- no need to make it inner.  Call it the "view model".

Comment: Thank you, you made a different to me and save me at least 5 hours, thank you for helping me, have a nice weekend!

Comment: @user1804033 no prob! glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

Good afternoon, it looks like you are passing the actual list property "a" to your view as its model.  Therefore in your view you should refer to the list as simply **Model** not **Model.a**

Comment: Perfectly made good sense, when creating a view, there is an option to select a 'strong type', what does that mean? to bind a view to a model type? @mreyeros